# What is the issue with my pyserial? I've already installed py serial using pip

Tags: python, arduino, serial-communication

I have installed Py serial using command prompt and when I write

```
    import serial
```

it doesn't give me an error but when I write

```
    s = serial.Serial("COM3",9600)
```

it gives me and error
[image: here]

For anyone wondering, I am trying to communicate to my Arduino using serial connection

Comment: [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Comment: @martineau its in the picture

Comment: You're missing the point — which is to **not** do it.

Comment: @martineau sorry, i have read it and i understand . my apologies . also, yes i have installed pyserial using pip

Comment: I know you installed it…you say so in your question. @rfkortekaas was the one who asked.

Comment: @rfkortekaas sorry, im quite new and i dont understand what u mean by serial.__file__

Comment: @rfkortekaas for me it doesnt output anything

Comment: @rfkortekaas it points an arrow to pip and says invalid syntax

Comment: @rfkortekaas oh and im also using python version 3 if you were wondering

Comment: Have you installed pyserial using `pip3`?

Comment: @rfkortekaas i thinkso. i have installed py serial with 
pip install PySerial

Comment: @rfkortekaas i did python -m pip freeze inmy command prompt and  this is what i got
cython == 0.29.22
future == 0.18.2
iso8601== 0.1,14
pyserial == 3.5
pyYAML==5.4.1